# Need hints about how to set up a probability model to calculate the expected value of a game.

Tags: probability

I am self studying probability from "Understanding Probability" - by Henk Tijms and one of the unsolved exercise questions is about formulating a probability model for the expected payoff of a lottery game. The question is as follows:

> In the daily lottery game "Guess 3" three different numbers are picked randomly from the numbers 0,1,...,9. The numbers are picked in order. To play this game, you must choose between "Exact Order" and "Any Order" on the entry form. In either case, the game costs 1 dollar to play.
>
> Should you choose to play "Exact Order" you must tick three different numbers in the order you think they will be picked. If those numbers are picked in that order, you win a 360 dollar payoff.
>
> Should you opt to play "Any order" you tick three number without regard for their order of arrangement. You win a $160 payoff if those three numbers are picked.
>
> Set up a probability model to calculate the expected value of the payoff amount for both options.

**Q1. How should I go about setting up the probability models asked in the question ?**

**Q2. Is there any intuition or general advice I can follow while setting up such probability models ?**

I have come up with the following solution for the expected values:

1. For one iteration of the **"Exact Order"** game, the player must choose 3 numbers in order. So probability of getting the three numbers = $\frac{1}{(10 * 9 *8)}$ and the payoff = 360 dollars. Also, For each game the player pays 1 dollar, implies
   **Expected value =** $(360 * \frac{1}{(10 * 9 *8)}) - 1$ **= -1/2 dollars**
2. One iteration of the **"Any order"** game is similar to that of "Exact Order" but with 6 permutations of the 3 numbers resulting in a win. So the probability of getting the three numbers = $\frac{6}{(10 * 9 *8)}$ and payoff = 160 dollars. Also, For each game the player pays 1 dollar, implies **Expected value =** $(160 * \frac{6}{(10 * 9 *8)}) - 1$ **= + 1/3 dollars**

**Q3. Is my solution, mentioned above, correct ?**

Comment: Did you mean $-1/2$ rather than $-1/12$?

Comment: Yes it should have been $-1/2$, corrected it.  Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be $X$ the event of guessing when playing the e**x**act order, and $Y$ when playing the an**y** order.

$P(X)=\frac{1}{10\times 9\times 8}\\
P(Y)=\binom{10}{3}^{-1}=\frac{7!3!}{10!}=\frac{6}{10\times 9\times 8}$

So both probabilities you calculated are correct.

$\begin{align}
E[Exact\ Order]&=360P(X)-1\\&=-\frac{1}{2}\\
E[Any\ Order]&= 160P(Y)-1\\&=\frac{1}{3}
\end{align}$

Everything you did was correct. I simply showed you in a different notation, but is essentialy the same.

Comment: I understand that $\binom{10}{3}^{-1}$ simplifies to $\frac{6}{10\times 9\times 8}$ but intuitively, why did you write $P(Y)$ as $\binom{10}{3}^{-1}$ ?

Comment: So, to formulate a probability model all I need to do is write the events in terms of random variables and use the right notations ?      Is there any other general intuition which might help me formulate probability (or mathematical) models in future problems ?

Comment: $\binom{n}{k}$ are the ways to select $k$ elements from $n$ options. I wrote $\binom{10}{3}^{-1}$ because it's easier to read than $\frac{1}{\binom{10}{3}}$ .In order to formulate this kind of probabilities the very first think you should do is learn some combinatorics, at least, about Permutations, Combinations, and their variants. Then go for the basic idea that probability are $\frac{favorable\ cases}{possible\ cases}$